# Get class property from jquery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, class-method

I have a class:

```
class MyClass{
    #arr= [];


    constructor(){
        $("body").on("click", ".myClass", function(e){
           //here, i need to access this.#arr, but unfortunatelly "this" no longer represents MyClass.
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function instead to preserve the `this` value, after which you can use `e.target` to get the element that was clicked.

```
$("body").on("click", ".myClass", e=>{

});
```

Comment: Yes, i thought of that, but how will i be able to get the clicked element then?

Comment: @kriskotooBG `e.target`.

Comment: huh, i didnt know that was a thing.  Thanks a million!

Comment: @kriskotooBG Happy to help.